# Ansible git module asks for password while using ssh key verification on update

Tags: git, ansible

I'm trying to set up automatic updates to my app.

I'm using ansible with ssh key verification.
It all works fine on just a clone to new directory but asks for my credentials when I'm trying to update contents of existing one with earlier version of the app.
The ssh key is obviously added to the repo and all of its submodules as it works while cloning and doesn't ask for password then.

I don't want to have credentials saved on the device.
Here's part of the playbook responsible for git operations:

```
- git:
    key_file: '/home/pi/ansible/key'
    repo: 'git@bitbucket.org:space/repo_with_submodules.git'
    dest: "{{ build_dir }}"
    update: yes
    version: main
    recursive: yes
    accept_hostkey: yes
```

How can I make it not ask for credentials or is there any other way to just update, without cloning the whole thing that doesn't ask for password?

Comment: Is *Git* asking for key verification, or is *ssh* asking for key verification? Given that Git with an ssh URL just runs ssh and leaves everything up to ssh, I think you're looking in the wrong place here. (But since you're using submodules, perhaps a submodule has an https URL and therefore Git is asking for https information.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the credentials are asked because of an HTTPS URL in `.gitmodules` of your repository, try and configure first in your Ansible playbook a:

```yaml
# Configures git.
---

- name: Use SSH instead of HTTPS proto
  command: "git config --global url.'ssh://git@'.insteadOf https://"
  sudo: no
```

That would force Git to always use SSH, which should work if your URLS are from BitBucket.

Comment: Yup, I've already had urls in .gitmodules set to ssh but looks like I've forgot to change them somewhere else. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: @optiguard Great! Well done.